# When calculating the variance of a linear combination of least squares estimators, what is C?

Tags: regression, self-study, variance

I am reading DeGroot and suddenly "C" comes out of nowhere.  I am not sure where he got C from and how to calculate it.  The context is linear regressions and calculating the variance of the prediction.  I understand in general, in linear combination of variance, Cs are weights but what are the weights here?

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks.  I guess he showed us C before defining C.  He goes on to define C in the next section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing prediction from a linear regression, these are the values of the regressors for the point at which you are predicting the outcome. In a bivariate regression, when predicting $y_i$ (the outcome of the point $i$), $c_0=1$ and $c_1=x_i$.